# Reapply JavaScript/jQuery after Ajax call in .NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I'm using uniform jQuery plugin and I'm using ASP.NET. Whenever I update my dropdown lists using the `UpdatePanel` Ajax call, the dropdown lists lose their styles.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply JQueryPlugin after update. Take a look at this [article](http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Run_a_JavaScript_function_after_every_or_specific_callback.aspx) for details.